# How to fix EBUSY: resource busy or locked in Ionic 3?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I use `ionic cordova run android` to run my Ionic 3 app on an Android device.
It gives the error below.

```
Android Studio project detected
(node:3780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or loc
ked, open 'E:\6124Petsoo_Sep5\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml'

    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1299:33)
    at ConfigFile_save [as save] (E:\6124Petsoo_Sep5\platforms\android\cordova\n
ode_modules\cordova-common\src\ConfigChanges\ConfigFile.js:93:12)
    at E:\6124Petsoo_Sep5\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\
src\ConfigChanges\ConfigKeeper.js:60:49
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ConfigKeeper_save_all [as save_all] (E:\6124Petsoo_Sep5\platforms\android
\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ConfigChanges\ConfigKeeper.js:58:31)
    at PlatformMunger_save_all [as save_all] (E:\6124Petsoo_Sep5\platforms\andro
id\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ConfigChanges\ConfigChanges.js:65:24)

    at updateConfigFilesFrom (E:\6124Petsoo_Sep5\platforms\android\cordova\lib\p
repare.js:102:41)
    at Api.module.exports.prepare (E:\6124Petsoo_Sep5\platforms\android\cordova\
lib\prepare.js:42:20)
    at Api.prepare (E:\6124Petsoo_Sep5\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:192:45)
(node:3780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection
 id: 1)
(node:3780) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I am using Ionic 3 and Angular 4 in my app. Can anyone help me fix this error?

Comment: try to `npm clear cache`.

Comment: try `cordova clean` and  `ionic cordova run android`

Comment: Do you use any  Anti-Malware/ antivirus software in your PC ??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what asking exactly, if it is about debugging the app in your mobile, just run the following command

```
ionic cordova run android --debug --device -l
```